# CanvasItem not overflowing outside canvas

Tags: jquery, json, uisearchbar, smartgwt, typeahead.js

Am using smartGWT 4.0.x and Firefox 21

Am trying to implement typeAhead search using third party jquery. I created a canvas and overrode the getInnerHTML() method to write the html for the search bar. I used the onDraw() method to load the jquery.

I got the canvas instance and in my vlayout, i added it by setting it into a 'canvasItem'. The typeahead function is getting called and am getting the value. But the dropdown feature from the jquery is getting bound within the canvas. Its not overflowing out of the canvas. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used the propery bringtoFront and sendtoback of the canvas to control the elements to be displayed at front.